# How to dispose from another class?

Tags: java, libgdx, dispose

I have a main class that implements ApplicationLister and a bunch of other classes that doesn't implement anything, what I  have in mind is this.

```
//I create a method for is disposing on my other classes
 public void disposable(){
  //things to dispose
}

// and then call the method on the main class

public void dispose(){
  classObj.disposable();
}
```

Is my idea any good? and also how do I know all the classes/methods that are disposable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interface in libgdx which foces you to implement a dispose method. It allows you to put all disposables into a list and dispose them at the end.  In the end it is not a bad idea to implement a dispose at every object which holds resources like for example the Assetmanager or a Screen implementation. But you do not need it for everything since the object does get distroyed when the garbage collector is running over it. You can not delete a object on purpose.

Take a look into the [Disposable Interface](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable.html) and the classes which implement this to know which classes you can dispose. As already mentioned it is used for classes which holds resources.

A simple class would look like this:

```
public class Foo implements Disposable{
    @override
    public void dispose()
    {
        //release the resources used here like textures and so on
    }
}
```

It does exactly look like your approach but you could add all disposables into a list to dispose when the game is closed:

```
ArrayList<Disposable> disposables = new ArrayList<Disposable>();
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
disposables.add(myFoo);

//game is running
//....
//
for(Disposable d : myFoo)
{
    d.dispose();
}
//end of the main
```

Try to use the Libgdx util classes.

Further reading for knowledge about disposing and why:
[Memory Management from libgdx Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management)

One importand sentense from here is:

> [...] implement a common Disposable interface which indicates that
>   instances of this class need to be disposed of **manually** at the end of
>   the life-time.

Comment: Thanks sorry for late feedback, so I can implement Disposable on any class right? then there's no need to call dispose() on the main class dispose() method.

Comment: yey you can implement the dispoable on any class. But you just need it for classes which have resources. I'd only implement it at such classes to make clear that they hold resources. No you dont need to call the dispose of the main but you should invoke the disposing of everything on system shutdown.